# White space at the bottom of page nothing helps

Tags: html, css

I have white space on the bottom of my page. I have tried various ways that have helped others, but none work for me, including padding, margin, height, auto and others.

Here is my code:

```css
.profwindow {
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    top: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.chatwwindow {
    position: relative;
    left: -210px;
    float: left;
    height: 370px;
    width: 250px;
    top: 280px;

    background-color: red;
}

.mapwindow {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 560px;
    right: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    top: -430px;
        
}

.navigation {
        position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 10px;
    top: -460px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
}

#mainphplogo {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    left: 40px;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="lt">
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainphplogo">
    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" height="100px"  ></a>
    </div>
    <div class="profwindow"></div>
    <div class="chatwwindow"></div>
    <div class="navigation"></div>
    <div class="mapwindow"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This is the smallest code code example that demonstrates the issue affecting the page, and as you can see, there is a black & white space at the end of page, which I have not able to remove.

Comment: Getting the white-space on this end.

Comment: yes thats the problem and i do not know how to remove that tried varies ways nothing help , i use float left for left side divs and float right for right side divs thats usually helps but not this time

Comment: Have you considered switching your elements to `position: absolute;` ? Also, you want to specify your `html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }`, and add `*,*::before,*::after { box-sizing: border-box; }` It looks like you want these elements to hover on the page and not float left or right. This should then get rid of your bottom white space.

Comment: and moreso, I think `position: fixed` may suffice better if you are trying to do what I think you're doing.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I would suggest adding 2 divs... first left column second right column. then float the 2 new divs left and you should be good.

Comment: make an answer with that and i will accept cuz i made this already :)

Comment: You want me to make a solution for you using position: fixed ? It seems as though you are trying to make a layout with tools on top of a map. I literally make these kinds of applications for government.

Comment: no tnx i solve this by removing float from all divs and add two more divs for left and right and add flow inside them but tnx

Comment: Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suggestion: switch to a responsive design using bootstrap grid or something similar.

For your concrete issue, removing the

```
float: right;
```

from .mapwindow will fix the extra whitespace because floating it sets the intial point far at the bottom and you're getting it up back with the

```
top: -430px;
```

So the initial position is still kept

Answer (score 0):

By adding

```
html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

to your css file I was able to get the blank space at the bottom to go away.

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.profwindow {
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    top: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.chatwwindow {
    position: relative;
    left: -210px;
    float: left;
    height: 370px;
    width: 250px;
    top: 280px;

    background-color: red;
}

.mapwindow {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 560px;
    right: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    top: -430px;
        
}

.navigation {
        position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 10px;
    top: -460px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
}

#mainphplogo {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    left: 40px;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="lt">
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainphplogo">
    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" height="100px"  ></a>
    </div>
    <div class="profwindow"></div>
    <div class="chatwwindow"></div>
    <div class="navigation"></div>
    <div class="mapwindow"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in your snippet it still shows the whitespace need to add a `overflow:hidden`

Comment: Of course I forgot to add it into my snippet. Fixed now.

Comment: overflow hiddent wont ... if my current window are bigger then a browser window overflow hidden will just cut the bottom of my div

Comment: Oh in full screen mode it still has a large area of white space. I only viewed it in the smaller window.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i solve this kind a simple method made a new two divs for right and left side and insert into them right and left side divs like this :

```css
.profwindow {
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    
    width: 250px;
    top: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.chatwwindow {
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    height: 370px;
    width: 250px;
    top: 75px;

    background-color: red;
}

.mapwindow {
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 560px;
    background-color: red; 
}

.navigation {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
}

.mainleft {
    float: left;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 800px;
}

.mainright {
    right: 10px;
    float: right;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="lt">
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainleft">
        <div id="mainphplogo">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" height="100px"  ></a>
        </div>
        <div class="profwindow"></div>
        <div class="chatwwindow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainright">
        <div class="navigation"></div>
        <div class="mapwindow"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```